# The faith of Abraham is uncertain...?

Tags: romans, abraham

According to Paul's letter to Romans Abraham had no distrust in God's promise though Sarah's womb was barren.  Rather his faith grew stronger in the promise of God. God was able to do what He had promised (Romans 4:18-21).  But according to the book of Genesis 16 Abraham listened to Sarah and he loved Hagar and she gave birth to Ishmael.

What do you say, is the book of Romans not conflicting with the book of Genesis???

Answer (score 4):

There is no conflict between Genesis and Romans. The Book of Romans (amplified by Hebrews) speaks about a life long exercise of faith with Abraham, not just one incident.  Did Abraham listen to Sarah, yes but that does not indicate that he stopped believing in the Lord’s ability to do what He promised.

In Romans 4:20, the KJV says that Abraham “staggered not at the promise of God THROUGH UNBELIEF.”  The key here is the unbelief.  The Greek word for ‘staggered not’ per Vines Expository Dictionary, says that “the verb suggests, not a weakness of faith, but a lack of it,” which is exactly what the verse says; Abraham did not experience a casting away of his faith but continued to believe.

In Genesis 15: 1-6, when Abraham questions God about the promise of the seed, Abraham asks if one of his servants children should be counted as the heir of the promise.   God says no to that idea and tells Abraham that heir of the promise would proceed **from his own bowels**.  So, it would make perfect sense that when Sarah presented him with the idea of the heir through Hagar, that Abraham would think that this may be the plan since Abraham would physically father the child. The bible says that after this incident (Genesis chapter 15) that Abraham believed God and God counted that belief for righteousness.

In Genesis 21:10-12, after the birth of Ishmael, the Lord tells Abraham that Ishmael was not the son of the promise. The Lord tells Abraham to “cast out the bondwoman and her son, for the son of the bond woman would not be heir with my son, even Isaac.” Then in verse 12 God states plainly that “in Isaac shall thy seed be called.”  Abraham continues to believe God as he put out Hagar and Ishmael, signifying that he trusted the Lord to provide the heir though Sarah.

Hebrews 11 tells us that Abraham continued to trust God through the attempted sacrifice of Isaac (Genesis 22).

So, whether Genesis, Romans or Hebrews, the bible is consistent in telling us that Abraham continued to believe God from the time he left Ur of the Chaldees to the attempted sacrifice of Isaac; and that belief was accounted to Abraham for righteousness.

Comment: Profound answer.  Thank you for this

Comment: You are welcome